# jquery ajax html special chars

Tags: php, jquery

javascript

```
var a="sadahdka sarr&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp"

jQuery.ajax(
                        {
                            type:"POST",
                            url:"function/postbai.php",
                            data:"a="+a,
                            success:function(html)
                            {
                                alert(html);
                            }
                        });
```

Before

```
var a="sadahdka sarr&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp"
```

After
why

```
$_POST['a']="sadahdka sarr"
```

Help
jquery ajax html special chars

Comment: Hi Sonj. Welcome to StackOverflow! If you find a reply answers your question, please select it as the answer- you can take as much time as you like to choose the answer.

Comment: Please ask your question more clearly. Do not write tags in the question.

Answer (score 3):

because `&` is a field seperater in the query string. if you want to preserve the `&` make sure you do `encodeURIComponent(a);`

Answer (score 1):

Your string isn't valid as a querystring, you either have to encode it with `encodeURIComponent` or let jQuery do it for you by passing an object :

```
var data = {a :"sadahdka sarr&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp"};

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "function/postbai.php",
    data: data
}).done(function (html) {
    alert(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape your string before sending it to the server and decode it in PHP.

JS:

```
data : "a="+escape(a);
```

PHP:

```
urldecode($_POST['a']);
```

Comment: You may want to look into `encodeURIComponent` as it better fits the escaping of characters for URL's