# how to include htmlspecialchars in ajax post

Tags: php, ajax

At the moment I have a form using ajax which just looks like this:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="">
```

Is it possible to make it more secure with this but still use ajax?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: str,
            beforeSend: function() {
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery ajax html special chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767957/jquery-ajax-html-special-chars)

Comment: Okay, then how do I use encodeURIComponent with the ajax code? ( I have edited original post)